# java file.delete() won't work

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I have created a properties file and I want to encrypt that keep the same folder encrypted properties file and delete the original properties file. When I do this on my java application first time it does correct way. But when I do this again it doesn't delete the created original properties file. When I try to delete that manually it gives me a try again message saying that "The action can't be completed because the file is open in java(TM) platform SE binary.Close the file and try again." After I closing my application it can be deleted manually. My code is as follows. Problem is on the propfile123.delete(). How can I resolve this problem.

```
//Encrypt the property file
        Encrypt_Decrypt encrpt= new Encrypt_Decrypt("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","properties\\"+name_of_propertice_file+".properties", mstr_pass);
        try {
            encrpt.encrypt();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Secure_File.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //delete the original properties file
        File propfile123= new File("properties\\"+name_of_propertice_file+".properties");
        System.out.println(propfile123.exists());   // always return true

        System.out.println(propfile123.delete());   //here returns false when I call at second time to this method.
```

Comment: Insufficient information provided. This code doesn't exhibit the problem described.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The evidence is clear that the reason the delete is failing is that **your application** still has the file open ... somewhere.

To resolve this, you need to figure out *where* you are opening the file, and make sure that you close it ... before you attempt to delete it.  (I suspect that the problem is something to do with your `Encrypt_Decrypt` class, and the way that you are using it.  But that's just a guess.)

Comment: But first time I do this it works. Second time it fails to delete.

Comment: Without an SSCCE, I don't think we can help you further with this.

Answer (score 7):

When you open a file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (new File ("somefile")));
```

if you don´t make a call to the method `close()` of `BufferedReader` you can not delete the file.

Always close the file before making any changes to it, even delete it or rename it. 
I hope to help you, greetings.

Comment: Came across this bad boy (a little late) but working on an older app.  Using `br.close()` wasn't enough, neither was using a `try(BufferedReader br..)` even through BR closes FR in this case, I had to create both the FileReader and the BufferedReader in the try with resource.  Once that happened the delete worked.